Is there a 64bit character constant in C++?
I'm trying to define a magic file number and I was hoping to be able to do something like:
auto magic = 'Magic123';

The maximum size of character constants seems to be 32 bits though so I have to resort to something like
auto magic = (static_cast<uint64_t>('Magi') << 32) + 'c123';

Which looks way less cool and will look even less readable once endianness is added.
I thought character contstants can be 64 bits for a while now, is that not true? Any hope it will be added?

This has a name c-char-sequence,  not character constant, its value is unspecified and has type int. That's all about c-char-sequence.

uint64_t magic = 0x4D616769'63313233u;  // Magi c123 would be more readable and portable

auto magic = std::hash<std::string>{}("magic123");?

What is your original problem you try to solve with something like this? What will this magic value be used for? How would that solve the original problem?

I would not recommend using a magic text. Just let your file start with a 128 bits) UUID. The kind of thing you're trying to do was used in old file formats but has proven to be very fragile (next to that you probably need some version info etc.)

@Someprogrammerdude Good question, I want the first 8 bytes of the file be "Magic123" with no zero after that. Newer format versions of this file might use different numbers.

@3CxEZiVlQ The error message that I get (VC) is too many characters in character constant. It's good to know what it's called in the C++ standard, but I would not be so quick to dismiss other names.

A long time ago I used a system of file formats that had a 32-bit header that was usually a combination of letters. To create this header there was a MAKE_ID macro, which took four arguments and used normal bitwise operations (SHIFT and OR) to combine these four values into an "id". Like MAKE_ID('I', 'L', 'B', 'M'). Could easily do something like that, but for a function and for eight values. similar to the answer by Eljay but using distinct arguments instead of strings.

Might be of interest to be aware of the history why C++ has this 'LMNO' four-character constant int.  C++ has it because C has it.  C has it because B has it.  B has it because BCPL has it.  BCPL has it because CPL has it.  I don't know why CPL has it — probably just for laughs.

@Fozi Right, character constant is 'a' and too many characters in character constant means 'a' is expected as a character constant but 'abcd' is given.

@Eljay This is because 'a' in C is int regardless of where it comes from. 'ab' is int, 'abc' is int, 'abcd' is int. 'abcde` overflows int.

@3CxEZiVlQ But 'abcd' is fine while 'abcde' is not. That's because e is a character and 'abcde' is a character constant with one too many characters. No offense, but this discussion about the name of things is pointless. Let's agree to disagree.

@3CxEZiVlQ However, I think you made me understand something. 'щщ' is a valid character constant/multicharacter literal/c-char-sequence because it does not overflow int. '' is not because  is more then 2 bytes. The core problem is that the character constant is only allowed to be int and not more. If it was allowed to expand like a numeric constant it could be allowed to be a bigger type, but alas, it's not. Is that the gist of what you are trying to say?

@Fozi char8_t, char16_t, char32_t exist, char64_t does not exist and 64-bit c-char-sequence is not useful.

BTW, with int64, you have endianess issue, just use std::array<char, 8>.

'Magic123' is a Multicharacter literal. It is conditionally-supported1, has type int and implementation-defined value. Presumably the platform you are trying this on uses 32 bit int, and only supports multicharacter literal up to 32 bits.

I.e. an implementation may support it, in some fashion that it documents, but is not required to.


I thought character contstants can be 64 bits for a while now, is that not true?

No, '' has always only been required to be 8 bits. It is allowed to be any size bigger than that.

Ok, so If I understand correctly what you and the others here are saying is that this feature is more of a multibyte character support (e.g. unicode) then a number formatting feature like 0x1234. That makes sense.

@Fozi it's not multibyte character support, that would be u'猫', U'猫' and L'猫'. It's basically a misfeature, presumably because some pre-standard implementation had it.

In that case I for one find it useful and I don't understand that 64 or even 128 bit character constants are not supported.

Also, if it's not multibyte character support, then why can't I write ''? Honest question, I think it's confusing.

@fozi You can already write integers in base 2, 8, 10, and 16. I don't think "base implementation-defined" is particularly sensible. Characters are not numbers

You could make your own operator""_u64 for this purpose.
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include<cassert> // Intentionally last, and lacking the space so it sorts last.

constexpr auto operator""_u64(const char* s, std::size_t size) -> std::uint64_t {
    assert(size == 8);
    std::uint64_t result = s[0] & 0xFF;
    result = (result << 8) | (s[1] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[2] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[3] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[4] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[5] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[6] & 0xFF);
    result = (result << 8) | (s[7] & 0xFF);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto magic = "Magic123"_u64;
    std::cout << std::hex << magic << "\n";
}

The operator""_u64 looks clunky, all unrolled like that and wordy.  But it optimizes very well.  Optimizers are amazing.
If you want to accept sizes other than strictly 8 characters, you'd need to modify the code accordingly.

That's not a bad idea. I was also thinking to just use a union from 2 uint32_t and a uint64_t and initialize it with {'Magi', 'c123'} but honestly this question is about the c-char-sequence. I'd like to see if I can understand that before I think about workarounds.

What's the comment on the cassert include about? include order shouldn't matter?

@AlanBirtles • The <cassert> include file is the only (or one of the few?) header file that is not idempotent.  It can be included multiple times, and it's behavior changes depending on #define NDEBUG or #undef NDEBUG preceding it being #include each time.  (A neat way to shoot yourself in the foot with ODR.)

I think that assert could be a static_assert instead?

@Fozi Using unions for type-punning is undefined behavior in C++. You can only read the value from the last member you wrote to.

@Someprogrammerdude From my reading this note guarantees that this works at least as well as a reinterpret_cast would, which for the types we talk about here is expected. We're not casting floats or class instances here, there are very clear memory layout requirements for all types involved. I don't see any UB here, it's all well defined.

changing NDEBUG within a program doesn't seem very wise...

I wouldn't spend _u64 on that one. Maybe _str64 or some longer suffix. Or even just an ordinary function std::uint64_t to_magic(std::string_view);. If I need strong guarantee on size, then the argument can be changed to std::span<char const, 8>, or char const (&)[8].

@AlanBirtles • C++ celebrating it's C heritage.  Ain't never gonna change!  No matter how much it hurts the language.  Because backwards compatibility is more important than the growth and evolution of the language.  :sadpanda:

The maximum portable size is 8 bits, not 32. Your specific implementation happens to use a higher value.
8 also implies that there's no portable 64 bits character constant.

I have not seen any platform that does not support at least 4 bytes in the last decade or two. I'm not targeting anything from the last millenium.

This is called c-char-sequence, not character constant, its value is unspecified and has type int. That's all about c-char-sequence. Hence, a 64-bit value can't be defined.

@Eljay's code is correct. You could also create a helper function to combines multiple characters into a uint64_t magic file number.
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t make_magic(const char* str) {
    return (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[0]) << 56) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[1]) << 48) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[2]) << 40) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[3]) << 32) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[4]) << 24) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[5]) << 16) |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[6]) << 8)  |
           (static_cast<uint64_t>(str[7]));
}

int main() {
    constexpr uint64_t magic = make_magic("Magic123");
    std::cout << std::hex << magic << '\n';
    return 0;
}


